# Remove back button for drawer page using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-native-router-flux, react-native-ios

I've been trying to create an app to learn react native, which has a login interface where upon successful authentication, the user gets redirected to a homepage with navigation drawer - the standard for most mobile apps today.

I've used [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) and [react-native-drawer-layout](https://github.com/iodine/react-native-drawer-layout) to implement this.

I got the drawer working but once I get to homepage (Recipes) from login page I can see a back button being shown, and I can't seem to set a drawer icon as stated in the react-native-drawer-layout API no matter what I try.

[image: Homepage with drawer open but shows back button]

I think the problem is with my Router, the scenes defined for this particular scenario is as follows.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
            titleStyle={styles.navTitle}
            sceneStyle={styles.routerScene}
            barButtonIconStyle={styles.barButton} >
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login"
          component={Login}
          title="Login"
          hideNavBar = {true}
          initial

        />
         <Scene
          key="recipes"
          component={Recipes}
          title="Recipes"
          hideNavBar = {false}
          hideBackImage = {false}
          //backButtonImage = {require('image!ui_nav_bar_hamburgher_icon')}
          onBack = {() =>{return null;}}
          rightTitle = "Bad Hombres"
          onRight = {() => { Alert.alert(
            'No puppet, No puppet',
            'You\'re the puppet!',)}}
          leftTitle ="Bigly"
          onLeft = {() => {Alert("Such a nasty woman..")}}
         // leftButtonImage={require('image!ui_login_email_icon')}

          panHandlers ={null}
        />
      </Scene>

    </Router>
  );
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm missing here? Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: backButtonImage should work. could be the Bad Hombres :)

Comment: ```backButtonImage = {require('image!ui_nav_bar_hamburgher_icon')}``` doesn't work anymore. Try with ```backButtonImage = {require('../path/to/your/image')}```

Answer (score 0):

I was used renderLeftButton to render drawer menu. You should use renderBackButton= { null } to hide back button. 
Document here https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md

Answer (score 0):

use hideBackImage prop on Scene component

Answer (score 0):

**I was trying to remove the back button and I finally found it.** There are two scenario.
First Import the View from react-native. If you want to remove the 'Back Text' title and want only arrow back button.

```
import { View } from 'react-native';

<Scene key="home" component={FooterMenu} title="User Home" renderBackButton={()=>null} />
```

If you want to remove everything.

```
<Scene key="home" component={FooterMenu} title="User Home" renderBackButton={()=><View/>} />
```